# 3D+ embedded spatial database option

Tags: database, 3d, spatial, shapes

We're developing an application that has to query 3D shapes (and query based on other parameters as well) within a bounding box. The number of shapes is more than I want to keep in memory, so I need a database to handle it.

Specifically, our primary operations are inserts and queries. We never modify existing data.

Because it's a desktop application, I'm trying to avoid the PostgreSQL and MySQL separate server types of things, hoping for something more simple for deployment. I found Spatialite but it does not index on the 3rd dimension, so it won't work.

I tried searching for kd-tree database but haven't found anything yet. I know there are kd-tree implementations, but getting it in database form would take a lot of effort to roll our own, so I'm trying to see if there is something already out there.

The application is in Haskell, but if we have to integrate with some other language, we might deal with that.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://sqlite.org/rtree.html

Comment: @notfed please post that as an answer as it certainly is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLite R*Trees](http://sqlite.org/rtree.html)

> Given a query rectangle, an R-Tree is able to quickly find all entries that are contained within the query rectangle or which overlap the query rectangle. This idea is easily extended to three dimensions for use in CAD systems.

Comment: Insert speed is thousands per second. Query speed is determined by number of results--few results is extremely fast, a few milliseconds, but 100,000 results takes 100's of milliseconds. But I realize that our query requirements are unrealistic. Wanting 10,000's per split second is not going to happen in a naive way. So... we might have to do something special for this after all.

Answer (score -1):

I would respectfully challenge your attempt to avoid PostgreSQL/MySQL. I'm experienced in PostgreSQL and it does the job you want and it is not difficult to administer. Certainly, anything else you find is not going to have the level of development and testing PostgreSQL does - so why bother?

Comment: As a simple non-technical user, if you installed a paint application, would you want to have to administer a postgresql database under the hood for it? We have a very focused requirement that really any SQL RDBMS is overkill for, but I'm seeing if we can use something existing to avoid writing all the disk level management and caching code when it's already been written many times in existing databases.